# Schema.sObjectType.(...).isUpdateable() method is returning true but should return false

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, schema, sobjecttype

In short, I'm trying to follow the PMD Source Code Analyzer Project, and I realized that before making an update I must validate whether the user has permission to change the field ([ApexCRUDViolation](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexcrudviolation)). It turns out that I need to make the test method meet this criteria and for that I created a permission set that does not allow the user to have this function, but instead of `Schema.sObjectType....isUpdateable()` returning **false** it is returning true, and **Immediately after the update operation, I have an exception thrown that says that the user does not have permission to perform the operation**, below is my logic.
How can I make it work?

**Controller Class**

```
public with sharing class ProductActivationController extends ResponseController{

@AuraEnabled
public static Response propagateChanges(List<OrderItem> products, Opportunity opportunity){
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    try {
        
        updateProducts(products);
        updateProjectManager(opportunity);
        
        return new Response(true, 'SUCCESS', products);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Database.rollback(sp);

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Error in the operation to update the order products.');
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, e.getCause());
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, e.getStackTraceString());

        return new Response(false, 'ERROR', 'An error occurred while processing the operation.', new Map<String, Object>{
            'cause' => e.getCause(),
            'message' => e.getMessage(),
            'stackTrace' => e.getStackTraceString()
        });
    }
}

private static void updateProducts(List<OrderItem> products) {

    if (!Schema.sObjectType.OrderItem.fields.Designation__c.isUpdateable()) {
        throw new ProductActivationException('Your user does not have permission to make changes to the field ' + 
        Schema.sObjectType.OrderItem.fields.Designation__c.Label + '.');
    }
    if (!Schema.sObjectType.OrderItem.fields.ADate__c.isUpdateable()) {
        throw new ProductActivationException('Your user does not have permission to make changes to the field ' + 
        Schema.sObjectType.OrderItem.fields.ADate__c.Label + '.');
    }

    Database.update(products);
 }

    public class ProductActivationException extends Exception{}
}
```

**TestClass**

```
@isTest
public class ProductActivationControllerTest {
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
        (logic to make all data)
    }
        @isTest
    static void shouldPropagateChangesError(){
        Order o = [SELECT Id FROM Order];
        User user = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias = 'johndoe'];
        List<OrderItem> items = [SELECT Id FROM OrderItem];
        for(OrderItem item : items){
            item.Designation__c = 'new des';
            item.ADate__c = Date.today();
        }
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
        opp.PM__c = user.Id;
        
        PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet();
        ps.Label = 'My Permission Set';
        ps.Name = 'My_Permission_Set';
        ps.Description = 'bla bla bla';

        insert ps;

        FieldPermissions fp1 = new FieldPermissions();
        fp1.SobjectType = 'OrderItem';
        fp1.Field = 'OrderItem.Designation__c';
        fp1.PermissionsEdit = false;
        fp1.PermissionsRead=true;
        fp1.ParentId = ps.Id;
        fp1.SobjectType='OrderItem';

        fieldPermissions.add(fp1);

        insert fp1;

        PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
        psa.PermissionSetId = ps.Id;
        psa.AssigneeId = user.Id;

        insert psa;
        
        System.runAs(user) {
            Test.startTest();
            ResponseController.Response response = ProductActivationController.propagateChanges(items, opp);
            System.assert(!response.success, 'OK');
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
(...)
(15888930135)|USER_DEBUG|[51]|ERROR|Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 802Ha000000IRD3IAO; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 802Ha000000IRD3: []
(...)
(15888996139)|USER_DEBUG|[52]|ERROR|Class.ProductActivationController.updateProducts: line 72, column 1
Class.ProductActivationController.propagateChanges: line 39, column 1
Class.ProductActivationControllerTest.shouldPropagateChangesError: line 281, column 1
(15889000283)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[52]|System.debug(APEX_OBJECT, ANY)
(...)
```

Comment: Permissions are "additive". You cannot remove permissions with a perm set, so if the user's profile or some assigned perm set already gives access, they have access regardless of additional perm sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phil mentioned in a comment, creating a new permission set assignment and assigning it to a user doesn't actually remove the permission if it's granted elsewhere, such as from a different permission set or the profile.

In addition, checking field permissions doesn't actually check if the user has access to the object (OrderLine) itself. The error "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" can mean that the user doesn't have sufficient access to the object or doesn't have sufficient access to a specific record. In other words, your unit test is demonstrating that your main logic isn't handling all possible security scenarios.

What you're missing from your main logic is:

```
if(!sObjectType.OrderItem.isUpdatable()) {
  // You don't have permission to update this object
}
```

As well as considering that the user might not have access to the order (e.g. sharing rules).

All of this checking is now obsolete, though. You can simply use the new security syntax:

```
update products as user;
```

The new `as user` modifier checks for all field, object, and record permissions, as if the user was submitting data from the UI or a standard API. There's no need to check individual fields or objects in modern Apex code. If an exception is thrown, the exception will contain the list of fields that are inaccessible, if any.